# What truly is a software?

Tags: battery, desktop-computer

Yes I agree, the question is rather elementary.

But what truly is a software?

How do we integrate a software and a hardware?

Is it true to think that a software basically means a hardware in disguise?

I have always thought of computer software as the control of electrical impulses that begins from the movement of ions from the battery and the control of the movement of charge {i.e., the manipulation of movement of charge in different direction or intensity} truly means a software. This manipulation (this CONTROL) basically means a software. And Hardware is the physical , stationary(not always stationary) parts in the computer.

So, Is it true to think software "THE CONTROL" that directs the flow of electron in the physical channels?

If my entire explanation is wrong, please guide me to the correct intuition and concepts.
Thanks in advance.

And also I don't know which tag I'm suppose to insert.

Comment: Think of it this way:  If you were baking a cake, hardware is the flour,yeast, oven and etc.  Software is the recipe that directs you how to make the cake.  The ingredients are worthless by themselves, but if you have the instruction you can turn them into a cake.   Similarly the software of a computer tells the hardware what to do.

Comment: So, software is basically a map that leads to a direction

Comment: a circuit is like water in a pipe. electricity flows through it, and logical circuits within it control where it flows to, and how it varies from one input to another. CPUs implement Instructions, that use specific bits of the circuitry to perform elementary tasks like arithmetic, boolean logic, and memory management, and coordinates their operation, such that a stream of instructions builds into a useful task. Anything below instructions is the purview of electrical engineers, and everything above is the realm of computer scientists. A CPU isn't a complete product without an instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise "I have always thought of computer software as electrical impulses that begins from the movement of ions from the battery and the control of the movement of charge" is wrong.

Software is a set of instructions - which are not electrical impulses - rather they boil down to a set of 1's and 0's which are recorded on a medium, and manipulate "impulses" you imagine to provide an output - ie, while software may be run, the actual software is simply a set of instructions, something like a recipe.

You are correct that hardware is generally the physical machinary, but what you are calling software is actually **execution/running** of software - the software itself would (typically) change - only the results.

Comment: oh sorry, I meant to say the control of electrical impulses and the guide that directs them to hardwares